# Sendmail Spamming Recipient

Tags: email, sendmail, spam, perl

I am using a perl script to send daily status to my gmail account.
For some reason, sendmail seems to be spamming gmail although I am only sending one email
Gmail is complaining about a failed verification, which seems to trigger sending the message to alternate relays. Since all relays point to the same account, it raises a spam flag ( ... receiving messages at rate ...)

This problem is related to the sending host, since sending emails to the same recipient from another host just goes through right away.

The recipient eventually (few hours) gets 5 copies of the original email

Note: Using postfix instead of sendmail works ....

Can anybody point me towards a solution?

```
Mar 23 07:00:01 myhostname /USR/SBIN/CRON[16720]: (root) CMD (perl /root/daily-check.pl^I)
Mar 23 07:00:01 myhostname /USR/SBIN/CRON[16721]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Mar 23 07:00:01 myhostname sendmail[16742]: r2N601Va016742: from=root@myhostname.isp.net, size=445, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201303230600.r2N601Va016742@localhost.localdomain>, relay=root@localhost
Mar 23 07:00:01 myhostname sm-mta[16743]: r2N6012b016743: from=<root@myhostname.isp.net>, size=680, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201303230600.r2N601Va016742@localhost.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Mar 23 07:00:01 myhostname sendmail[16742]: r2N601Va016742: to=myaccount@gmail.com, ctladdr=root@myhostname.isp.net (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30445, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (r2N6012b016743 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 23 07:00:02 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 23 07:00:02 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: r2N6012b016743: to=<myaccount@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@myhostname.isp.net> (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120680, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [IPv6:2a00:1450:4001:c02::1b], dsn=4.2.1, stat=Deferred: 450-4.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that
Mar 23 07:00:03 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: STARTTLS=client, relay=alt1.aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 23 07:00:03 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: r2N6012b016743: to=<myaccount@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@myhostname.isp.net> (0/0), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120680, relay=alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. [IPv6:2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b], dsn=4.2.1, stat=Deferred: 450-4.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that
Mar 23 07:00:04 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: STARTTLS=client, relay=alt2.aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 23 07:00:04 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: r2N6012b016743: to=<myaccount@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@myhostname.isp.net> (0/0), delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=120680, relay=alt2.aspmx.l.google.com. [IPv6:2607:f8b0:400e:c00::1b], dsn=4.2.1, stat=Deferred: 450-4.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that
Mar 23 07:00:05 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx3.googlemail.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 23 07:00:06 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: r2N6012b016743: to=<myaccount@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@myhostname.isp.net> (0/0), delay=00:00:05, xdelay=00:00:05, mailer=esmtp, pri=120680, relay=aspmx3.googlemail.com. [IPv6:2607:f8b0:400e:c00::1b], dsn=4.2.1, stat=Deferred: 450-4.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that
Mar 23 07:00:07 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx2.googlemail.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 23 07:00:07 myhostname sm-mta[16745]: r2N6012b016743: to=<myaccount@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@myhostname.isp.net> (0/0), delay=00:00:06, xdelay=00:00:06, mailer=esmtp, pri=120680, relay=aspmx2.googlemail.com. [IPv6:2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b], dsn=4.2.1, stat=Deferred: 450-4.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that
```

Comment: Type a list of your crontab and your perl script. Because of the ^I (tab character) in  the log above I suggest you delete the crontab line that contains your script and retype it. Delete the line, exit crontab editor and then reinsert it again. You may have more "whitespace" characters that interfere with the execution and as a result mail get sent to your Gmail account constantly.

Comment: How may DAILY reports has been delayed? Your problem MAY vanish after a few messages accepted by the recipient as "non spam" => make SURE the recipient does not keep the messages in SPAM/JUNK folder.

Answer (score 2):

You sendmail gets "retry later" reply from every gmail MX server it tries to contact.
Sendmail tries all five MX servers published by gmail.
It *may be* a [greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) in disguise.

1. Does the email *finally* gets through (with delivery delay)?
2. How many (other) messages per day myaccount@gmail.com receives?

Google Help/Documentation:

- ["The Gmail user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate..."](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6592?hl=en)
- [Receiving limits](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1366776)

Comment: Gmail messages rates start at 180 emails per minute. I am getting the warning as of the first message. For clarity, the account is not receiving other emails for other sources during that time.

Comment: gmail.com is served by 5 MX servers (see `nslookup -type=mx gail.com`). You sendmail TRIES to send message by every one of them because they give "try later" response.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Does free version of Gmail have same limits?

Comment: Gmail as a system has these limits. This has nothing to do with mail hosting offered by Gmail.

Comment: Would the first try go through if certificate valuation had passed? Since the rate issue is invoked on the first message, it may be bogus.